# How do Italians pronounce the names of programming languages?

Tags: pronunciation

Is there a standard form of pronunciation for programming languages in Italy? Is it preferable to pronounce in English or in Italian? In other words, suppose I'm explaining, in Italian, something about software development, will it sound more natural to say *"C diesis"* or *"C Sharp"?*

*Note: I asked about C#, but the same applies to many other languages, such `C++` and `VB.NET`, for example*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The rules, as far as I can tell, are the following:

## Letters are pronounced the Italian way

- HTML: *acca-ti-emme-elle*
- XML: *ics-emme-elle*
- C: *ci*

## Nouns are pronounced as English, which often is similar to Italian

- Prolog
- BASIC
- Smalltalk

## Exceptions

- C++ is pronounced *ci-più-più* (*più* being "plus" in Italian), probably because the ++ unary operator is also called "più più'"
- C# is often pronounced with a unholy *ci-sciarp*, because the lanugage C is *ci* and the sharp translates as "cancelletto", so "ci-cancelletto" doesn't sound right, it's hard to say.
- F# is also *effe-sciarp*, similarly to C#.
- SQL is either *siquel* or *esse-cu-elle* so it's either of the first two rules

Comment: I have always pronounced BASIC as Italian (bà-ʃi-k vs the English pronunciation ˈbeɪsɪk)

Comment: Sei sicuro di non voler dire "diesis" al posto di "cancelletto"? Nel senso, un cancelletto é un "#" mentre il simbolo del linguaggio C Sharp è un "♯". Comunque, eccellente risposta, grazie mille :)

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa, you are right that the _sharp_ of C# should be a _diesis_, but, as you can read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29#Name), the number sign (pound, hash...) has replaced it in the official name of the language for practical reasons

Comment: @nico, rather 'ba:-zik, and also 'bæ:-zik. But I agree with you, the English pronunciation is not often used

Comment: @Walter Tross: may be an AE vs BE thing... but the OED definitely reports ˈbeɪsɪk

Comment: @Wnico *'ba:-zik* is used by Italians that don't know which is the proper pronunciation, but theoretically the correct pronunciation in Italian is the English one, *'bæ:-zik*

Answer (score 4):

I think every language gets pronounced in Italian in the original way, with the exception of C++ which usually is "C più più" (instead of "plus plus").

As for C#, it is definitely "C sharp".

In the examples above, phones are pronounced in the "Italian way", that is, "C" is *chee* and not *see*. This applies to every language (php is "pee acca pee"). So a comprehensive answer is: we use original names but they're usually pronounced with  Italian phonetics.

Comment: And, unfortunately, *àccess* (with the ‘doppia c’ and stress on the ‘a’). I don't know if this qualifies as a programming language.

Comment: “Ci” (chee) or “si” (see) for “C”?

Comment: I confess I pronounce php and html with the italian spelling. And even when I speak English, I have to actively remember to pronounce correctly API and IDE.

Comment: @DaG: la prima (Ci), anche per C#, che quindi diventa un mix fra italiano e inglese

Answer (score 2):

There is no strict rule. Most of the times the pronunciation is a mixture of English and Italian.

For example, C# is usually pronounced as *ci-sciarp* mixing Italian pronunciation for *C* and the English pronunciation for the symbol *#*.

Some languages are completely translated to an Italian pronunciation (such as *Ci* for C, and *Ci più più* for C++).

In other cases the change is more subtle. For example, Python is usually pronounced something like *Pàiton* (no *th* sound and the accent in a different place).

---

The *only* real rule is that acronyms are pronounced as every acronym: using Italian pronunciation for the letters:

- PHP is *pi-acca-pi*
- SQL is *esse-qu-elle*

Comment: Actually I've heard SQL pronounced in every possible way, including stuff that's neither Italian neither English ("sìchiuel", anyone?)

Comment: @MatteoItalia SQL was first called SEQUEL. Some people stick with the old pronounciation.