# Origine della parola "cancelletto" per il carattere #

Tags: etymology, nouns

Leggendo questo [post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2093/how-do-italians-pronounce-the-names-of-programming-languages) 
ho imparato che il carattere # viene chiamato "cancelletto" in italiano. Questo vocabolo mi è sembrato molto curioso. Sapreste dirmi quale sia l'origine di questa parola?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Il nome *cancelletto* non è solamente tipico dell'italiano. Infatti anche in inglese si può chiamare *gate* (cancello) e anche *fence* (recinzione), e in molti altri modi elencati [qui](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign#Other_names_in_English) (sebbene molti di questi siano raremente usati).

Non ho trovato nessuna fonte ufficiale riguardo l'etimologia del nome, sebbene sembri abbastanza plausibile che il nome derivi semplicemente dalla somiglianza con le sbarre di un cancello/di una recinzione in entrambe le lingue.

Answer (score 3):

Penso (ma non ne sono sicura) che si riferisca al fatto che somiglia alle sbarre di un cancello